# R: updating a variable defined in a function using a helper function without a return value

Tags: r, function, recursion, environment-variables, helper

Reproducible code

```
# recursive helper function
# a = array representation of the binary tree
# i = position of the root that we are trying to add to inorder_a
# inorder_a = array representation of a up till i
add_node <- function(a, i, inorder_a) {
  print(paste("a:", paste(a, collapse = ' '), 
              "i:", i, 
              'a[i]:', a[i],
              "inorder_a:", paste(inorder_a, collapse = ' '), 
              sep = ' '))
  if(is.na(a[i]) == FALSE) {
    # add the left child of the root node in position i, which is in position 2*i
    add_node(a, 2*i, inorder_a)
    # add the root node in position i of a
    inorder_a <- append(inorder_a, a[i])
    # add the right child of the root node in position i, which is in position (2*i + 1)
    add_node(a, (2*i)+1, inorder_a)
  }
}

# main function that calls add_node() to return the in-order traversal of binary tree array a
get_inorder_traversal_recursion <- function(a) {
  n <- length(a)
  
  # corner cases
  if(n <= 1) return(a)
  
  # initiate output array
  inorder_a <- c()
  
  # add binary tree a, whose head/root is in position 1
  add_node(a, 1, inorder_a)
  
  return(inorder_a)
}
```

When I call `get_inorder_traversal_recursion(c(1, NA, 2, 3))`, I get the following print out from the `print` function that I set up to see what's going on iteratively. The print out is as expected where `inorder_a` is being updated iteratively.

```
[1] "a: 1 NA 2 3 i: 1 a[i]: 1 inorder_a: "
[1] "a: 1 NA 2 3 i: 2 a[i]: NA inorder_a: "
[1] "a: 1 NA 2 3 i: 3 a[i]: 2 inorder_a: 1"
[1] "a: 1 NA 2 3 i: 6 a[i]: NA inorder_a: 1"
[1] "a: 1 NA 2 3 i: 7 a[i]: NA inorder_a: 1 2"
```

However, the return value of `get_inorder_traversal_recursion(c(1, NA, 2, 3))` is `NA` because `inorder_a` within `get_inorder_traversal_recursion(c(1, NA, 2, 3))` never got updated, which is what I had expected would happen with the call to `add_node(a, 1, inorder_a)` within `get_inorder_traversal_recursion`.

Can someone explain why `inorder_a` was never updated within `get_inorder_traversal_recursion(c(1, NA, 2, 3))` when the helper function `add_node()` was called up update it?

The reason why I don't have a return value to `add_node()` is because I'm not sure where to put it...

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Scope

Comment: Values in R are not passed by reference. If you pass in a vector to a function and make change to that vector, those changes are only visible to the function itself. The original value of the variable is not changed. If you need to update values, you should return the updated value from your function so you can replace the outer scope value.

Comment: that explains it!